# Can't get POST response

Tags: node.js, post, towerjs

I'm using Tower.js 0.4.2-20.

I sent a GET and POST request for HTML FORM tag.
'GET' request is no problem response.
but 'POST' request is the following error returned.

I'm missing router setting?

routes.coffee :

```
Tower.Route.draw ->
  @resources 'service'
  @match '/service/add', to: 'service#add', via: 'post'
```

ServiceController.coffee :

```
class ServiceController extends App.ApplicationController
  index: ->
    @render text: "GET"
  create: ->
    @render text: "POST"
  add: ->
    @render text: "ADD"
```

index.html :

```
<form method='POST' action='service/add'>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Add'></div>
</form>
```

Error :

```
Error: Forbidden
at Object.exports.error (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:44:13)
at Object.module.exports [as handle] (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:54:41)
at next (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at multipart (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:57:27)
at module.exports (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:57:9)
at IncomingMessage.module.exports (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:68:11)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
at Object.resume (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/pause/index.js:25:18)
at store.get.next (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:311:15)
at /var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:333:9
```

Comment: The error is not that important. What we need to help you is your node app code

Comment: Sorry.Wrote to node app code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First guess: your form's relative URL is the problem. Change your `form`'s `action` attribute to `/service/add` and see if that helps. The 403 forbidden error you are getting probably means the POST request is going to a different URL path that you expect. For example, if your form is at `/pages/service`, the form will submit to `/pages/service/service/add` due to the relative url.

2nd guess: Ah. got it.

```
at Object.module.exports [as handle] (/var/www/html/melissa/manage/development/yoshiaki-tanaka/node_modules/tower/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:54:41)
```

That `crsf` module is probably checking for a cross site request forgery token in your form, which would take the form of a `<input type="hidden" name="crsf_token" value="YOUR_CRSF_TOKEN">` tag (or something like that). Read the docs on the CRSF middleware you are using about how to create the proper `<form>` tag HTML including the CRSF token.

Comment: Thank you Peter Lyons.
current path is 'example.com/service' when form's action attribute changed to 'add'.
<form method='POST' action='add'>
but happen same error.